# Selenium webdriver issue in clicking hyperlink

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am having a problem while trying to click on a hyperlink using Selenium Web-driver. I tried using Selector as well as xPath and nothing seem to work. All I am trying to do is click on the hyperlink

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" id="id_34" alt="Title: Pending Changes-type: Web Intelligence-owner: Administrator-last viewed time: Nov 21, 2018 11:03 AM">Pending Changes</a>
```

Comment: You can edit your question-post with additional details - no need to put it in comments. Also, format the code. Here are some points on [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

The element is [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Java Solution:

  - `linkText`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Pending Changes"))).click();
    ```
  - `cssSelector`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[id^=id_][alt^='Title']"))).click();
    ```
  - `xpath`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@id,'id_') and starts-with(@alt,'Title')]"))).click();
    ```

Comment: Hi,Thanks.But it didn't worked for me.As there is 4 tables an inside one of the table there is one row having this pending changes hyperlink.could you please help

Answer (score 0):

Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Pending Changes")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("d_34")).click();
```